# with Apache Camel, how to consume a message in a MQ only after other components have processed a message?

Tags: apache-camel, jms

We use Camel and ActiveMQ (and Talend ESB as well).

We need to process a message throw some components, send it to a AMQ named "A' then and only then wait for an other message to be consumed from an other  queue named "B". How can I design the route to do so ? If I set a JMS component for "B" after an other component it won't consume the MQ but produce a message to it.

A workaround would be to set a second path starting with a cTimer long enough for the first part or the route to achieve,  then consume MQ "B", but I would like a more clean solution.

Comment: Your question is, to make your queues consume messages alternatively. Is it???

Comment: Can you try to explain better, the question is confusing. You can look at Control Bus EIP to control routes: http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html